# Android soft keyboard showing problem

Tags: android

I'm trying to control soft keyboard using this:

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(filterText.getWindowToken(), 0);
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .showSoftInput(filterText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

But nothing happens on the device when i call this code. What can cause such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a

```
EditText mEditText;
```

then you should set:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

For a textview,

```
TextView mtextview;
```

you can set:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

android:inputType="text"
```

in the xml file. Upon clicking on the textview, you will pop up the keyboard.

Comment: Hi, I am not understanding , what is showSoftInput. Can you please give a clue on that?

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue where the soft keyboard was showing up when I first entered the activity and I didn't want it to.  This was messing up my scrollview.  I was able to keep if from doing this by setting the following in the manifest file in the activity that I was dealing with: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"