# Issue with Soft Keyboard and Edit Text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an Edit Text at the bottom of my app. I want to achieve that always when it gets a Touch Event, the Soft Keyboard appears scrolling the whole window to the top, so that my EditText remains visible.

The problem is that sometimes the window does not scroll at all and the Edit Text remains hidden behind the Soft Keyboard. The weird thing is that, in those moments, if I press anything or interact with other elements in the window, apparently it refreshes or something like that and then it scrolls correctly to the top, allowing me to see the Edit Text.

I have try different things and this is my end code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@android:color/black">

<my.Custom_Edit_Text
    android:id="@+id/my_custom_edit_text"
    style="@style/my_custom_edit_text_Style"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:maxLength="@integer/data_title_max_length"
    android:text="@string/my_custom_edit_text_default" 
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

This is my Custom_Edit_Text code, where I handle the onTouch event:

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I have also set this attribute in the Manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: are you told about when the touch event is occur the activity is overlap right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post gave me the clue to solve my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/5989385/1382250

I just tried to change my Edit Text for a Text View and now it works perfectly (scrolls the window in all cases).

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

and

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Let me know using both this are helpful to you or not and also use scrollview in the layout where your virtual keyboard is creating problem it also help a bit

put your whole layout which is distroting in a scrollview

Comment: My app is limited to portrait modus so hiding keyboard on rotation wouldn't help me. I already use the adjustPan configuration and tried to put everything in a scrollview (I forget to mention it in my question sorry). I found a solution using a TextView instead. But thank you for your tips anyway, they are pretty useful.